# Google push notifications - DOMException: Registration failed - push service error

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to enable push notifications on my website using VAPID keys.
When i include the *gcm_sender_id* and remove the *applicationServerKey* from the *pushManager.subscribe* method, it runs fine.

Only when i enable VAPID keys and remove the gcm_sender_id from manifest.json file. i get the foloowing error.

```
DOMException: Registration failed - push service error
```

I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: I'm getting this but only on Brave

Comment: @Anthony solution for Brave: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/2301#issuecomment-570114852

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I encountered this error in Brave browser. By default, Google Services for push messaging are disabled in Brave. To enable this, open the following URL in brave:

```
brave://settings/privacy
```

After this, enable the flag "Use Google services for push messaging":

[image]

Source:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3195#issuecomment-848036637

Comment: Do you know how to enable it on a phone ?

Comment: This worked! but can anyone explain how will the user know to first enable this option irrespective of browser? This is so bad

Comment: It boils down to "The default is Privacy, and notifications are bad, even if well intentioned".  Blame the scammers, spammers, and general idiots for making this happen.

Comment: You're a hero, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my case,I was trying to run firebase messaging on a flutter web.
My Browser was BRAVE.

It always failed with an exception of `firebase fcm registration push servic error`.

I followed @Nicodemuz answer, but it didn't solve the issue. I get the same error.

The only solution was setting Google chrome as my executable.

Anyhow the issue is not with firebase or flutter, it's with the brave browser itself.

Comment: @YasserCHENIK Nope 

Comment: Issue still exist in Brave . 2023

Answer (score 2):

The applicationServerKey that i was using in the pushManager.subscribe method was somehow incorrect.
It worked when i regenerated the keys in node using the following module.

```
const webpush = require('web-push');
const vapidKeys = webpush.generateVAPIDKeys()
```

Comment: do you know how to generateVAPIDKeys in angular12?